# What is the difference between kmemdup_nul() and kstrndup() in Linux?

Tags: c, linux-kernel

They are similar functions, but what is the exact difference between them? The Linux documentation states:

> Note: Use kmemdup_nul() instead if the size is known exactly.

Comment: You can tell what the difference is by looking at the [source code](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/plain/mm/util.c). `kstrndup()` calls `strnlen()` to possibly reduce the passed in length, but `kmemdup_nul()` uses the passed in length as-is.

Comment: @IanAbbott, better to give links to Elixir. In that case OP may browse the code besides the fact of syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both functions allocate the needed memory through `kmalloc()` and then place a `NUL` terminator at the end of the allocated buffer. The only difference between the two is that `kstrndup()` first calls `strnlen()` to calculate the length of the string and therefore the needed size, thus scanning the string.

You can see `kmemdup_nul()` as an optimized version of `kstrndup()`. If you already know the length of the string, you can avoid the initial scanning and just use `kmemdup_nul()` passing in the length as argument. This saves time since the string doesn't need to be scanned, and it's the reason why you see that note.

Moreover, `kstrndup()` saves space if the string is shorter than `max`, so in case you don't know the length of the string, even though `kmemdup_nul()` would work as well, you might want to call `kstrndup()` instead to potentially save space.

You can clearly see from the code that the only difference between the two functions is the call to `strnlen()`. Here's the source code, from [`mm/util.c`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.5/source/mm/util.c):

```
/**
 * kstrndup - allocate space for and copy an existing string
 * @s: the string to duplicate
 * @max: read at most @max chars from @s
 * @gfp: the GFP mask used in the kmalloc() call when allocating memory
 *
 * Note: Use kmemdup_nul() instead if the size is known exactly.
 *
 * Return: newly allocated copy of @s or %NULL in case of error
 */
char *kstrndup(const char *s, size_t max, gfp_t gfp)
{
    size_t len;
    char *buf;

    if (!s)
        return NULL;

    len = strnlen(s, max);
    buf = kmalloc_track_caller(len+1, gfp);
    if (buf) {
        memcpy(buf, s, len);
        buf[len] = '\0';
    }
    return buf;
}
EXPORT_SYMBOL(kstrndup);

/**
 * kmemdup_nul - Create a NUL-terminated string from unterminated data
 * @s: The data to stringify
 * @len: The size of the data
 * @gfp: the GFP mask used in the kmalloc() call when allocating memory
 *
 * Return: newly allocated copy of @s with NUL-termination or %NULL in
 * case of error
 */
char *kmemdup_nul(const char *s, size_t len, gfp_t gfp)
{
    char *buf;

    if (!s)
        return NULL;

    buf = kmalloc_track_caller(len + 1, gfp);
    if (buf) {
        memcpy(buf, s, len);
        buf[len] = '\0';
    }
    return buf;
}
EXPORT_SYMBOL(kmemdup_nul);
```

Comment: @GenZhang well, if there was a security issue *in those functions* I would be **very worried**. The functions *per se* are completely fine, what could happen is that some developer using the two functions could misuse them and cause memory corruption. One example could be calling `kstrndup()` with a `max` that is too large, therefore causing the internal `strnlen()` to scan past the end of the buffer into invalid memory. The same could happen with `kmemdup_nul()` anyway, if passing a wrong size.

Comment: @GenZhang this could cause a kernel panic if `strnlen()` hits invalid memory. Other than that, if `kstrndup()` or `kmemdup_nul()` are incorrectly called with a length that is too large, that could lead to copying part of memory that doesn't belong to the caller, and this could ultimately end up exposing the contents of kernel memory to userspace (for example if this is done by a kernel module to copy data that is then sent back to userspace).